# Filter GetFiles() on multiple criteria

Tags: vb.net, directoryinfo

Wasn't sure how to word my question title. but hopefully this will be quick.

I have a bunch of PDF files within a folder, I want to get the recent modified or created date of a certain type of file.  My code works but it gives me results of all the PDF files. I only want results of certain names.

For example. within my "c:\temp\" I have some PDF files that starts with just about the same 3 first letters followed by numbers or more letters.

File names such as tes8796, fes8897895, bas232. etc etc. I only want to be shown results of "fes" and "bas" files, I do not want to see "tes" files...

Any ideas?

I believe it should look something like this {"fes*.pdf", "Bas*.pdf"})

My code that works, (I only want to get result of only "fes" and "bas" fils.)

```
Dim pathx As String = "C:\temp\"
Dim directory = New DirectoryInfo(pathx)
Dim from_date As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24)
Dim to_date As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim files = directory.GetFiles().Where(Function(file) file.LastWriteTime >= from_date AndAlso file.LastWriteTime <= to_date)
For Each filx In files
    ListBox1.Items.Add(filx)
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.  First, you can apply the PDF filter at the start: `directory.GetFiles("*.pdf")`, then just extend your function conditions:

```
Dim names() As String = {"fes", "bas"}

Dim files = di.GetFiles("*.pdf").Where(
        Function(file) (file.LastWriteTime >= from_date _ 
               AndAlso file.LastWriteTime <= DateTime.Now) _
                  AndAlso (names.Contains(file.Name.ToLowerInvariant.Substring(0, 3)))
            )

For Each filx In files
    Console.WriteLine(filx)
Next
```

The problem is that it depends on the file starting names to always and forever be 3 chars.  Also, look at your code: once you get your array, you are looping thru it to post it to the ListBox.  *Usually* the cool kids use LINQ to *avoid* loops.  So, to fix both issues:

```
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(di.GetFiles("*.pdf").Where(
        Function(f) (f.LastWriteTime >= from_date AndAlso f.LastWriteTime <= DateTime.Now) _
            AndAlso names.Any(Function(n) f.Name.ToLowerInvariant.StartsWith(n))
            ).ToArray)
```

I got rid of var names which already exist in NET as Types such as `Directory` and `File`.  The second function filters on the names array, then the results are pumped *directly* into the listbox items collection.

In almost all cases, a plain loop will be faster:

```
Dim myfiles = directory.GetFiles("*.pdf")
For Each f In myfiles
    If f.LastAccessTime >= from_date AndAlso f.LastWriteTime <= DateTime.Now Then
        For Each s As String In names
            If f.Name.ToLowerInvariant.StartsWith(s.ToLowerInvariant) Then
                Console.WriteLine(f)
                Exit For                     ' abort when found
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
```

- probably more understandable for a self proclaimed *newbie in VB.NET*
- this can be incrementally debugged
- it is 2 to 100  times faster to process (depending the number of files and name filters)<sup>a</sup>
- will work with varying file name filters
- combines the finding/filtering operation with posting to eliminate the extra loop (`Console.WriteLine` could add to Items or add to a List as needed.)

<sup>a</sup> <sub>Whether the time difference *matters* depends on how it is used and the load.  If it runs continuously to process many, many files it might matter.  As part of a desktop app, probably not.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The `GetFiles` method that you're calling is overloaded and allows you to specify a single pattern to match.  You can either call that method twice (once for each pattern) and then combine the results or else you can retrieve all files with a single call as you are and then add another condition to your `Where` call to filter ny name as well as date/time.

Comment: I figured as much, but I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to VB. so maybe you can PLEASE edit what I have to get the results what I want?

Also, there will be more file names not just two. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You were very close. I would do something like this:

```
    Dim pathx As String = "C:\temp\"
    Dim directory = New IO.DirectoryInfo(pathx)
    Dim from_date As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-24)
    Dim to_date As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim files = directory.GetFiles().Where(Function(file) file.LastWriteTime >= from_date AndAlso file.LastWriteTime <= to_date AndAlso file.Name.EndsWith(".pdf") AndAlso (file.Name.StartsWith("fes") OrElse file.Name.StartsWith("bas")))
    For Each filx In files
        ListBox1.Items.Add(filx)
    Next
```